# Large dataSet to virtual memory?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, memory, virtual

**Over View**

I Have a service that Picks Data from SQL Server Tables into a dataset, and this dataset is then used to upload the data to a Central server over the internet.

I can not remove the dataset concept since the database i am accessing is of a different application, of which numerous users are connected to it concurrently, and that database does **NOT** have proper indexes or structures. Thus when my services queries the tables row by row, the database locks. Hence i have to pick all the data i need in one go and release the database.

**Challenge**

The challenge i am facing is when it comes to a table having millions of rows, the server memory (Private Working Set in Task Manager) usage goes over 2 GB, and thus on a low end server the server hangs.

**Question**

Is there any way i can set the Application to use the Virtual Memory of the system, as Virtual memory can be set to any value.

Or what should i do to minimize memory usage without having to keep querying the main database?

Comment: Why don't you just switch from read_committed to snapshot_isolation? With snapshot isolation your read-queries will not lock you database

Comment: Thanks, let me use snapshot_isolation as a solution for the deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this is what you're looking for.

> A memory-mapped file contains the contents of a file in virtual
>   memory. This mapping between a file and memory space enables an
>   application, including multiple processes, to modify the file by
>   reading and writing directly to the memory. Starting with the .NET
>   Framework 4, you can use managed code to access memory-mapped files in
>   the same way that native Windows functions access memory-mapped files,
>   as described in Managing Memory-Mapped Files in Win32 in the MSDN
>   Library.

Comment: Thanks, Let me try it out.